# JPA Hibernate Composite Id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to retrieve data from two tables. Tab1 and Tab2.

Tab1 has these columns :- 
tabId(Foreign key with Tab2.tabId)(Primary Key), 
tabType(Primary Key), 
tabAdd(Primary Key), 
tabUser

Tab2 has these columns :- 
tabId(Primary Key), 
location, 
name, 
description.

Really appreciate quick help!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should edit the post and show us DB diagram because your description isn't clear. I think if we should have more data :) you have 3 PK on tab1? Which relationship is between them? Greetings :)